# Problem generating d.ts files from p5.play.js when using tsc

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc, .d.ts

I wanted to generate a d.ts file for p5.play.js as there aren't any and since p5.play.js is a big library typing it out would be a pain and I am very new to d.ts files show I only know how to declare function and p5.play.js has properties as well. But when I use try to create it, it creates an empty d.ts file with `export {};`

Here are the things I have tried:

1. I tried using tsconfig.json with tsc to generate the files but the result was `export {};` and here is the config I used for tsc:

```
{
  // Change this to match your project
  "include": ["src/"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Tells TypeScript to read JS files, as
    // normally they are ignored as source files
    "allowJs": true,
    // Generate d.ts files
    "declaration": true,
    // This compiler run should
    // only output d.ts files
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    // Types should go into this directory.
    // Removing this would place the .d.ts files
    // next to the .js files
    "outDir": "dist"
  }
}
```

and is the src folder I had p5.play.js file

2. I tried using d.ts make with main.js and again is just created a d.ts file with: `export {};` and here is my main.js for dts make:

```
require('dts-generator').default({
        name: 'p5.play',
        project: 'src/',
        out: 'p5.play.d.ts'
});
```

again in the src, I had p5.play.js.

If it helps here is the npm for dts gen/make https://www.npmjs.com/package/dts-generator
And Here is the p5.play.js library: https://github.com/molleindustria/p5.play/blob/master/lib/p5.play.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had the same problem as you so instead of finding a predefined p5.play.d.ts, I created my own file for p5.play. The file is in my GitHub repository and I hope it helps you!!

Link to the file -> https://github.com/VisualCode44/Definition-File

Comment: This worked thank you very much I have been waiting for an answer for 2 months now